# How can I use systemctl from within a docker container (run on ubuntu 20.04, with ubuntu 18.04 base)

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, docker

I'm trying to start a docker container with systemd as the init process so I can run multiple services from that container, and I get the following weird error:

Systemd is listed as PID 1 when I run top, but none of the services i've enabled through systemctl are running, and trying to systemctl status them gives me `system has not been booted with systemd as init process (PID 1)`

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV container docker
ENV LC_ALL C
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN sed -i 's/# deb/deb/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y systemd systemd-sysv \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/ \
    && ls | grep -v systemd-tmpfiles-setup | xargs rm -f $1

RUN rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/* \
    /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev* \
    /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl* \
    /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/plymouth* \
    /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*

...assorted aptget installs...

ENV LOCAL="yes"

...assorted utils scripts...

RUN useradd --create-home fractal \
    && usermod -aG sudo fractal \ 
    && echo 'fractal:password1234567.' | chpasswd

...assorted utils scripts...

ADD bootstrap.sh /home/fractal
ADD entry.sh /home/fractal
ADD fractal-input.rules home/fractal

RUN chmod +x /home/fractal/bootstrap.sh \
    && chown -v -R fractal:fractal /home/fractal
RUN chown root:root /run/user
RUN chmod +x /home/fractal/entry.sh


...adding assorted services...

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
ENV init /lib/systemd/systemd


....assorted services enabled....

CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use systemd within a Docker container without major effort.  Most people use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) instead.

Comment: My coworkers have gotten it working on the same image with Arch and OSX machines, is there some reason Ubuntu would be harder?

Comment: Googling around, there are blog posts (https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/24/how-to-run-systemd-in-a-container/, https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/) that basically say "use podman" and reference a bug (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3629) where people claimed it worked then broke.

In the best case, you have to make your containers privileged which is a measure of last resort as it allows the container to have root on the host.

You either have to do all of that or do `apt install -y supervisor`